# Regular expression replace $(Key) in text file with value from dictionary

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I want to do something like this, I have a dictionary with keys and values, and a text file like this:

```
Hello my name is $(Name) and my favorite movie is $(Movie).
```

I want to read in the file and replace the occurrences of $(...) based on the values in the dictionary, so in this case the dictionary would have a key for Name and Movie.

How would I go about doing this?  If I parsed through each word, what would be the regular expression to match $(AnyWord), or would it be better to do something like this:

```
foreach(var word in file)
{
    if (word.length > 3)
    {
        if (word.substring(0,2)=="$(" && word.substring(word.length-1)==")")
           Lookup word in dictionary 
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a MatchEvaluator to do the replacements:

```
var replacements = new Dictionary<string,string>();
//populate the dictionary
string file = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("filepath");
file = Regex.Replace(file, @"\$\((?<key>[^)]+)\)", new MatchEvaluator(m => replacements.ContainsKey(m.Groups["key"].Value) ? replacements[m.Groups["key"].Value] : m.Value));
```

If there are any syntax errors I apologize. I'm at work at the moment with no C# compiler so I'll have to fix them when I get home.

Comment: Looks good, small mistakes: the word boundary before `$` and after `)` will not work, since `$` and `)` are non word characters, you should change it to `\B` not a word boundary, so it would match when on the left/right is a non word character. And the closing bracket needs escaping ==> `@"\B\$\([^)]+\)\B"` should be the correct regex.

Comment: Thanks for the fixups, stupid mistake with the unescaped closing parenthesis. Wasn't aware that the word boundaries wouldn't match either so thanks for that. Though, in heinsight, it's probably best to leave off the boundaries altogether in case they aren't ALWAYS meant to be separated from other strings. `"\$\([^)]+\)"` should be fine as the pattern, thanks stema

Comment: How do I edit it so that it will match Hi$(name)Hi, Hi $(name)Hi, and
Hi ($name) Hi?

Comment: So you want the dollar sign inside the brackets? Change the pattern to `\(\$(?<key>[^)]+)\)` Also, see my edit of this answer for the **proper** MatchEvaluator lambda expression @Matt

Comment: Sorry I didn't see you wanted both $(key) and ($key) `(?:\(\$|\$\()(?<key>[^)]+)\)` should be the pattern you need. @Matt

Comment: I had a typo. I meant. How do I edit it so that it will match Hi$(name)Hi, Hi $(name)Hi, and Hi $(name) Hi?  TO do this i just did not use \b or \B

Answer (score 1):

If your file is not to big, an easy solution would be to do it the other way around. Loop through all items in your dictionary and replace the tokens:

```
foreach(var item in dictionary) {
    var token = string.Format("$({0})", item.Key);

    file = file.Replace(token, item.Value);
}
```

Comment: Well, I actually need to look at all the words for other reasons already and my dictionary could become very large, so is the way you suggested better or is doing a parse check on each word on top of doing whatever else i need to do with the word better

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex to find strings like $(word):

```
/(\$\(\w*\))/i
```

Explained:

```
/                      # regex delimiter
    (                  # matching brackets
        \$             # the $
        \(             # the (
            \w*        # \w = a to z
        \)             # the )
    )                  # close matching brackets
/xi
```

modifiers:
i = case insensitive,
x = ignore whitespace in regex (so you can make it readable and make comments like this)

Comment: This is a C# question, please follow the C# regular expression specification. The RegEx flags are specified in the "options" parameter of the various RegEx functions, and patterns need not have delimiters such as they do in js,php..etc